# Shortest distance from 3D point to 3D line

Tags: excel-formula, geometry

I have a line AB constructed by the two points:

```
A:      "X": 3609859.464
        "Y": -288646.389
        "Z": 5232776.002
```

```
B:      "X": 3627454.491,
        "Y": -273763.234,
        "Z": 5222031.489
```

I also have a point Xn with these coordinates:

```
        "X": 3626785.577,
        "Y": -274291.458,
        "Z": 5222356.006
```

How do I calculate the shortest distance from Xn to AB?

I will eventually use this in an excel spreadsheet if anyone has a usable on already!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make vectors AB and AX

```
AB.x = B.x - A.x
AB.y = B.y - A.y
AB.z = B.z - A.z
and similar for AX
```

Find projection of X onto AB line using scalar (dot) product

```
P = A + AB * (AB.dot.AX) / (AB.dot.AX)
where 
AB.dot.AX = AB.x * AX.x + AB.y * AX.y + AB.z * AX.z
```

Needed distance is length of vector XP

Answer (score 0):

Using a moving point on `AB`, the squared distance is

```
(XA + t AB)²
```

Differentiating on `t`, we cancel the derivative

```
(XA + t AB) AB = 0
```

or

```
t = - XA.AB / AB².
```

This gives us the squared minimum distance

```
(XA - (XA.AB / AB²) AB)² = XA² - 2 (XA.AB)²/AB² + (XA.AB)²/AB² = XA² - (XA.AB)²/AB².
```